# selecting text using awk command

Tags: linux, ssh, awk

```
USERNAME=root
HOSTS="192.168.122.91 192.168.122.102 192.168.122.180"

SCRIPT="df -h /dev/vda3 | grep '/export/brick' | awk '{print $2}' ";
for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
   (ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}")
done
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
/dev/vda3              27G  722M   26G   3% /export/brick
```

desired output = `27G`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `$2` to have it interpreted by `awk` inside the ssh connection:

```
SCRIPT="df -h /dev/vda3 | grep '/export/brick' | awk '{print \$2}' ";
```

Also, note you can squeeze it a little bit, using the `grep` condition inside the `awk`:

```
SCRIPT="df -h /dev/vda3 | awk '/export\/brick/{print \$2}' ";
```